# How to make Drools KnowledgeAgent be dependant a custom component with Spring configuration?

Tags: spring, drools

I have my KnowledgeAgent setup as

```
<drools:kagent kbase="kbase" id="knowledgeAgent" new-instance="false" >
    <drools:resources>
        <drools:resource source="classpath:change-set.xml" type="CHANGE_SET" />
    </drools:resources>  
  </drools:kagent>
```

So it scans the change-set.xml from classpath for resources. And I have another component which will dynamially generate the change-set.xml based on rulefiles found on disk. The spring configuration for this is

```
<bean id="changesetHandler" class="ChangesetHandler" autowire="byName" lazy-init="true" />
```

The problem here is that the change-set.xml is generated by my custom component, but I cannot set the Drools KnowledgeAgent component to be dependant on it as it follows it's own [schema](http://pastebin.com/nQW73KK9) which does not seem to have `depends-on` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that a knowledge agent listens for changes, it should reload the knowledge base as soon as your bean generates the change set. Why not load a default empty change set initially and then load the dynamic change set when it has been generated?

Personally I avoid the Drools-Spring components. I find it easier to create a service within my application, which holds my knowledge base. I can then define whatever dependencies I like within that service and ensure that any initialisation has been completed.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, excellent workaround on loading the change-set "manually" from the service and skipping the xml conf on this part altogether. I'm using Grails, so I'm pretty much tied with using Spring.

Comment: I use Spring all the time. I just don't use the Drools-Spring stuff. :)